# How to set the Default value for DropDown when post back in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working with MVC3 and I have a dropdown that I need to set the default value from the database.

When I select a value in the dropdownlist I get a postback and the value I selected is selected even after the postback. How do I get the default value, <--Select Project--> as selected value again after the postback? How is this done in MVC?

Below are the Controller and Views that I use.

**My Models**

```
namespace BugTracker.Models
{
    public class BugModel
    {
        public List<BugModel> InsertBug {get; set;}
        public List<BugModel> Bugs { get; set; }
        public Int16 BugID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
        public string Description {get; set;}
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Version is required")]
        public string Version { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "BuildNumber is required")]
        public string BuildNumber { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "CreatedDate is required")]
        public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "GetDate is required")]
        public string GetDate { get; set; }

        public List<BugModel> GetProjects { get; set; }
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "ProjectName is required")]
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }

        public List<BugModel> GetEmployee {get; set;}
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public int CreatedByID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "EmployeeName is required")]
        public string EmployeeName {get;set;}
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "CreatedBy is required")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public List<BugModel> GetCategory { get; set;}
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category is required")]
        public string Category { get; set;}

        public List<BugModel> GetSeverity { get; set;}
        public int SeverityID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Severity is required")]
        public string Severity { get; set; }

        public List<BugModel> GetPriority { get; set; }
        public int PriorityID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Prirority is required")]
        public string Prirority { get; set;}

        public List<BugModel> GetReleasePhase { get; set;}
        public int ReleasePhaseID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "ReleasePhase is required")]
        public string ReleasePhase { get; set;}

        public List<BugModel> GetTypes { get; set; }
        public int TypeID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Type is required")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
 public List<BugModel> GetBugHistory { get; set; }    
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "AssignTo is required")]
        public string AssignTo { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**My controllers are**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]    
public ActionResult BugDetails(FormCollection form,string Projects,string Prirority,string CreatedBy,BugModel model)    
{
    var modelList = new List();    
    ViewBag.Projects = new SelectList(GetProjects(), "ProjectId", "ProjectName");    
    ViewBag.Prirority = new SelectList(GetPriority(), "PriorityID", "Prirority");    
    ViewBag.CreatedBy = new SelectList(GetEmployee(), "EmployeeID", "EmployeeName");    
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=BugtrackerNew;Data Source=SSDEV5-HP\SQLEXPRESS"))    
    {    
        SqlCommand dCmd = new SqlCommand("Filter", conn);    
        dCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;    
        conn.Open();    
        dCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProjectID", Projects));    
        dCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PriorityID",Prirority));    
        dCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CreatedByID",CreatedBy));    
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(dCmd);    
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();    
        da.Fill(ds);
        for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)    
        {
            model.BugID = Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BugID"]);    
            model.Title = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Title"].ToString();    
            model.Description = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Description"].ToString();            
            conn.Close();             
           return View(modelList);
        }
    }
```

**My view page is**

```
using (Html.BeginForm())    
{ %>   

    <%: Html.DropDownList("Projects", (SelectList)ViewBag.Projects)%>    

    <%: Html.DropDownList("Prirority", (SelectList)ViewBag.Prirority, "Select Project")%>  

    <%: Html.DropDownList("CreatedBy", (SelectList)ViewBag.CreatedBy, "--Select Project--")%>
}
```

When the page returns from postback, I would like the default value to be selected, but in MVC there is no page load method. So, please could somebody point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using DropDownListFor(), you could pass the wanted project into your model on your view.

Example:

```
@{ var projects= (IEnumerable<Projects>)ViewBag.Projects; }


@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProjectId, projects, string.Empty)
```

In short, use your model to determine the selected value in a dropdownlist, provide the possible value through your viewbag.
If your property on your model is the default value of the property type, the dropdownlistfor will show the first value of the list with possible values.

Comment: sorry yar it is not working could u explain me other easy way plz don't mind plz

Comment: At this moment your view doesn't have a clue on which project to select in your dropdownlist. you'll have to pass this towards the view somehow( by model, viewbag, viewdata... ) Then connect the list to that property by DropDownListFor()